# Is there sdk to create new account in Polygon through web3

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, polygon

Is there any functions or API to create a new account in polygon,

**like hashgraph in hedera, is there any function or API to create a new account through code in the polygon?**

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var ethers = require('ethers');  
var crypto = require('crypto');

var id = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
var privateKey = "0x"+id;
console.log("SAVE BUT DO NOT SHARE THIS:", privateKey);

var wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);
console.log("Address: " + wallet.address);
```

Then interact with polygon using a json rpc provider pointing to then to sign messages.